# SQL Add foreign key to existing table

Tags: mysql, database, key

I have started reading up on SQL and am currently reading the Head First SQL book, and I am using MySQL . I have got to a point where it explains how to create a new table with a foreign key and move data from the single table to the new table. What is not mentioned is how to create the foreign key in the old table and assign it fk data. These are the tables:

```
my_contacts:
FirstName
LastName
Profession
```

Phone

```
Profession:
Prof_ID PK
Profession
```

So what I did was add an additional column to the my_contacts called Prof_ID and populated it with

```
UPDATE my_contacts SET prof_id = (
  SELECT prof_id FROM my_contacts WHERE my_contacts.profession = profession.profession
);
```

this works perfectly matching the professions names from the 2 tables and populating the my_contacts.prof_id. Afterwards I created a constraint and a FK on this column and dropped my_contacts.profession.

What I am struggling to wrap my head around is how the statement runs. From what I have read SQL process the statement how ever it wants unless specifically told to do something else with order by and group by. So why does that statement match correctly? I am struggling to understand how its running through the data, unlike with a language like C# I know the order the events take place. Is this like a loop statement?

Thanks for your time and always.

Comment: Is there are typo in the UPDATE statement? Did you mean ```UPDATE my_contacts SET prof_id = (
  SELECT prof_id FROM``` ***profession*** ```WHERE my_contacts.profession = profession.profession);```?

Comment: is your question answered?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is like a loop. All rows of `my_contacts` are updated, since you have no `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE` statement. You use a `SELECT` statment to find the correct value for each row of `my_contacts`. This works, becasue `my_contacts.profession` changes its value for each row of `my_contacts`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried to test this with some other examples tables the book has. I used a select and an inner join on the 2 tables and irrespective of which order I joined the tables the results followed the order of the one table. irrespective if it was the left or the right.

Comment: The order is not relevant, because nothing depends on it. Your UPDATE statement will produce as many SELECT statements as there are rows in my_contacts.

Comment: So the UPDATE statement is what has the "loop" function? i.e. ROW1 my_contacts.profession = profession.profession therefore my_contacts.prof_ID = 1 ROW2.....etc. Where a SELECT statement with out ordering just spits out what is fastest?